# how upload video with text in facebook using sharekit?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am new to ios.

i have upload video in facebook using sharekit successfully but text should not share with video.

can any one help me.

sorry for my english

Comment: Sharekit is not working any more for iOS. So go for the facebook's official iOS SDK.